# Automatically spawn an Azure Batch AI job periodically

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I want to automatically start a job on an Azure Batch AI cluster once a week. The jobs are all identical except for the starting time. I thought of writing a PowerShell Azure Function that does this, but Azure Functions v2 doesn't support PowerShell and I don't want to use v1 in case it will be phased out. I would prefer not to do this in C# or Java. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no option available to trigger a job on Azure Batch AI cluster. Maybe you want to run a shell script which in turn can create a regular schedule using system's task scheduler. Please see if this doc by Said Bleik helps:

> https://github.com/saidbleik/batchai_mm_ad#scheduling-jobs

I assume this way you can add multiple schedules for the job!

Answer (score -1):

Azure Batch portal has "Job schedules" tab. You can go there, add a Job, and set a schedule for the Job. You can specify the recurrence in the Schedule

Scheduled jobs

Job schedules enable you to create recurring jobs within the Batch service. A job schedule specifies when to run jobs and includes the specifications for the jobs to be run. You can specify the duration of the schedule--how long and when the schedule is in effect--and how frequently jobs are created during the scheduled period.

Comment: Hi, this is about Batch AI and not regular Batch – and as far as I can see, Batch AI does not have a "job schedules" tab.